# Mongoose TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in [object Object]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongodb and for the past couple days I have been trying to get my entries into my mongolab instance but have not had any luck. It seems when I execute the save call I get an error stating:

`TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in [object Object]`

The [object Object] they are referring to is my Color schema.  I havent been able to find an answer yet and thought I would post here to work in parallel while I research more.  I have pasted a snipit of what I am using in hopes that it is just something stupid I am doing.  TIA!

```
mongoose.connect(config.db.mongodb);
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var Color = new Schema({
     hex    :   {type:String, required: true, trim: true}
    ,perc   :   {type:String, required: true, trim: true}
});
var Img = new Schema({
     path   :   {type:String, required: true, trim: true}
    ,color  :   [Color]
});
var imgModel = mongoose.model('Img', Img);

exports.addImage = function(req,res){
    //First check to see if we already have the image stored
    imgModel.findOne({path: req.query.path}, function(error, image){
        if(error){ 
            console.log("Error");
            res.json(error);
        }
        else if(image === null){
            //There is no image so just store the info
            var image_data = {
              path:     req.query.path,
              color:    req.query.color
            };

            var img = new imgModel(image_data);

            img.save(function(error, data){
                //*** This error block below is where I am 
                //    entering and the message is displayed
                if(error){
                    console.log("Oh noo: ",error);
                    res.json(error);
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Saving: ",data);
                    res.json(data);
                }
            });
        } else{
            //The path is already here
            //res.json("Image already in db");
            console.log("Image already in db");
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: are you sure req.query.path is returned a valid value? Put in a `console.log(req.query.path)` to make sure the value is what you expect

Comment: Yes it is the path of my image.  Sorry I removed all my console.logs to shrink the post some.  Perhaps I should have left them in :)  Something to note, It doesn't error in that first error block.  It errors out in the error block when I call img.save.  However after your comment I went to check the contents of the color object and my values are freakin weird.  I think that that maybe the issue.  I think it is something when I am unescaping the string passed in that it is messing somethign up.  Have to hop into a meeting right now.  Will chekc when I get back.  Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it was due to the way my color object was being unescaped when the request was being handled.  Upon entering it was seeing the object but the nested values were not valid and therfore was throwing off the write tot eh db as it was expecting Strings. I ended up doing a POST instead and passing the json object in the data param and then reading it back out through the body and it works as expected and has automatically created the db as desired.  Thanks Noah for the response!